# Equivalence between dual estimates

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $H$ a Hilbert space and $X$ a measure space; let $U(t):H\to L^2(X)$ an operator defined for all real $t$. I'm considering the following estimates:
$$\Vert U(t)f\Vert_{L_t^qL_x^r}\leq\Vert f\Vert_H$$
and
$$\Vert\int (U(s))^*F(s)ds\Vert_H\leq\Vert F\Vert_{L_t^{q'}L_x^{r'}}$$
where $^*$ indicates the adjoint and $'$ the conjugate exponents.
Are they equivalent?
I have some problems in dealing with the integral in the second estimate; my idea is to define an operator
$$AF:=\int (U(s))^*F(s)ds$$ from $L_t^{q'}L_x^{r'}\to H$ in order to find its adjoint and so the relationship between their norm. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does it help you to know that if $T$ is a bounded linear operator then $T$ and $T^*$ has the same operator norm? Your operator $A$ is the dual of the operator $U$ considered now as an operator $H\to L^qL^r$.

Comment: Your suggestion is just the point I'm trying to check:the proof of the fact that A is the adjoint of U; I'm a little bit lost with the pairing dual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just some formal symbol pushing below:

$\newcommand\Real{\mathbb{R}}$Let $\langle,\rangle$ denote the duality pairing for $Y = L^q_tL^r_x$ and $Y' = L^{q'}_t L^{r'}_x$. And let $(,)$ denote the $L^2(X)$ inner product (which is really just $(a,b) = \int_X ab \mathrm{d}x$, assuming we are working over real valued functions for now). Formally we have

$$ \langle y,y'\rangle = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_X y y' \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}t = \int_{\Real} (y,y') \mathrm{d}t $$

Now let $y = Uz$.

We have that $(Uz,y') = (z, U^* y')_H$ where $(,)_H$ is the $H$ inner product by definition.

So

$$ \langle Uz,y'\rangle = \int_{\Real} (z,U^*y')_H\mathrm{d}t $$

The first factor is independent of $t$, so from linearity of the inner product you get

$$ \langle Uz,y'\rangle = (z, \int_{\Real} U^* y'\mathrm{d}t)_H = (z, Ay')_H$$

giving that, at least on the formal level, that $A$ is the correct dual operator.

Comment: There's something to make precise dealing with the domain of definition of the various operators

Comment: Which is why I wrote "formal symbol pushing". In terms of domains, what you really want is $Y' = L_t^{q'} L_x^{r'} \cap L^\infty_t L^2_x$. For reasonable $X$ you expect this space to be dense in $L_t^{q'} L_x^{r'}$. But the verification of this fact depends on your knowledge of the space $X$: for example if $X$ is $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the Lebesgue measure (which would be the case in practically all applications to PDEs), then this is entirely trivial.